# Use BetterTTV or FrankerFaceZ on Website other than Twitch

Tags: javascript, replace, twitch, emoticons

Is there any way to use eg [BetterTTV](https://betterttv.com/) or [FranzerFaceZ (FFZ)](https://www.frankerfacez.com/) on a website other than twitch.tv to replace emotes?

I want to show onstream alerts on twitch (implemented via browser source). The messages sent often contain emotes like *OMEGALUL* or *PogU*.

I know I could download the images and replace the emotes in the string. That is already working. However, there are always some emotes missing (because I would need to implement them all).

So is there a way to use one of the emote replacement systems on a page other than twitch?

So eg this message

```
Hey PogU :)
```

should become

```
Hey <img src="...."> :)
```

I did not find any possibilities, but as there is at least for BetterTTV an option to implement the javascript file for there has to be a way.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution outside of here? I am trying to do the same currently!

Comment: Hey @AaronSoto, unfortunately not. But I just posted my approach that worked (with some drawbacks) as answer for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not what I initially intended, as this is *limited to the emotes I downloaded*, but my quick and dirty approach was (using Laravel - so pure php would be without helpers like `storage_path` or `dd`):

**Caution:** Those downloads take quite some time. So you will run into timeouts if you just run them with an eg 30s **php timeout**. So either start it from CLI or set the time limit to infinite (eg `set_time_limit(0);` or in php.ini: `max_execution_time = 0`)

## Step 1: Download the emotes

### Alternative #1: BTTV

```
<?php

// Download emotes first and put them into a json (multiple times using offset): https://api.betterttv.net/3/emotes/shared/top?offset=1199&limit=100
// Merge them into one emotes.json file
function downloadBTTV() {
    $emotes = json_decode(file_get_contents(storage_path('emotes.json')), false, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
    $used_filenames = [];
    $used_emotes = [];
    foreach($emotes as $emote) {
        try{
            $url = 'https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/' . $emote->emote->id .  '/1x';
            $filename = $emote->emote->code . '.' . $emote->emote->imageType;
            if(!isset($used_filenames[$filename])) {
                $used_filenames[$filename] = 0;
            }
            $used_filenames[$filename]++;
            $full_filename = storage_path('emotes/'  . $filename);
            if(!is_file($full_filename) && in_array($emotes->emote->code, $used_emotes)) {
                file_put_contents($full_filename, file_get_contents($url));
                $used_emotes[] = $emote->emote->code;
            }
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            dd(get_defined_vars(), $emote);
        }

    }
}
```

### Alternative #2: FFZ

#### 1) Get FFZ image ids

```js
// Open page https://www.frankerfacez.com/emoticons/wall?q=&sort=count-desc&days=0 and scroll a lot down
// Then execute the following js code on the page

var emotes = {};
document.querySelectorAll('a.thumbnail').forEach(function(el, index){
    var href = el.getAttribute('href');
    var name = el.querySelector('h3').textContent.toLowerCase();
    var id = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf("/")+1, href.indexOf('-') - href.lastIndexOf('/') - 1);
    if(!emotes.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        emotes[name] = id;
    }
});
console.log(Object.keys(emotes).length)
copy(emotes);
```

#### 2) Download the images in PHP

```
<?php
// 2a) Create a variable like that from the clipboard (copied in javascript in step 1)
$ffz_emotes_json = <<<'EOL'
{
  "pog": "210748",
  "omegalul": "128054",
  //...
}
EOL;

function downloadFFZ() {
    global $ffz_emotes_json;

    $emotes = json_decode($ffz_emotes_json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
    $new_emotes = [];
    $skipped_emotes = [];
    foreach($emotes as $emote => $id) {
        $url = 'https://cdn.frankerfacez.com/emoticon/' . $id .  '/1';
        $filename = $emote . '.png';
        $filename_gif = $emote . '.gif';

        $full_filename_png = storage_path('emotes/'  . $filename);
        $full_filename_gif = storage_path('emotes/'  . $filename_gif);

        if(!is_file($full_filename_png) && !is_file($full_filename_gif) ) {
            file_put_contents($full_filename_png, file_get_contents($url));
            $new_emotes[] = $emote;
        } else {
            $skipped_emotes[] = $emote;
        }
    }
    dd($new_emotes, $skipped_emotes);
}
```

## Step 2: Create the emotes dictionary

Now, that you have all those images stored in your storage path, we need to create a dictionary to look them up (as in this approach it is done via javascript).

```
<?php
function generateEmotesJS()
{
    $files = glob(public_path('img/emotes/*'));
    echo "window.EMOTES = {\n";
    /** @var DirectoryIterator $fileInfo */
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator(public_path('img/emotes/*')) as $fileInfo) {
        if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
        echo '    "' . $fileInfo->getBasename('.' .$fileInfo->getExtension()) .'": "' . $fileInfo->getExtension() .  "\",\n";
    }
    echo "};";
}
// store this output in your javascript file
```

## Step 2: Replace emotes in messages

```js
// You already have something like this in your file from the previous step
window.EMOTES = {
    "!treat": "png",
    "(ditto)": "gif",
    "02ayaya": "png",
    // ...
};

// call this function to replace the emotes:
window.replaceEmotes = function(message)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/59664804/936284
    return message.split(/([\W])/).map(function(el, index){
        if(index % 2 === 0) {
            lower = el.toLowerCase();
            if(EMOTES.hasOwnProperty(lower)) {
                return '<img src="/img/emotes/' + lower + '.' + EMOTES[lower] + '" alt="' + el + '">';
            }
        }
        return el;
    }).join("")
}

// You can now call this:
console.log(replaceEmotes('Hey PogU :)'));
// Returns: Hey <img src="/img/emotes/pogu.png" alt="PogU"> :)
console.log(replaceEmotes("Hey ho OMEGALUL"));
// Returns Hey ho <img src="/img/emotes/omegalul.png" alt="OMEGALUL">
console.log(replaceEmotes("Test Kappa\nTest > all <3"));
// Returns: Test <img src="/img/emotes/kappa.png" alt="Kappa">
// Test > all <3
```

Like I said, quick and dirty. If you have time, you sure find a better approach. Maybe reverse-engineering the chrome extensions for replacement makes more sense ;)